# In BPMN - how to model interface with details (fields) between two components?

Tags: interface, components, bpmn

I've been wondering how to model interface between two components using it's rectangular representation (not lollipop) with all the details (attributes, operations).

I have two components and interface that lets them to "talk" to each other.

[image: Base state]

Using "lollipop" notation I would do this in this way:
[image]

But I didn't know how to attach my interface definition to this flow.
**Is it correct to attach it to the line of Information Flow?** What type of assotiation use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found in OMG specifiaction the following description.
[image]

The component providing the interface **REALIZE** it. The one that consume it - **USES** it.

Recreating the diagram gave me this state:
[image]